# Reading message from Kafka with java.util.List in avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to read the message from Kafka using consumer with the following properties

```
value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
specific.avro.reader=true
```

And the schema is

```
{
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "MyDto",
          "namespace" : "test.dto",
          "fields" : [ {
            "default" : null,
            "name" : "version",
            "type" : ["null","string"]
          }, {
            "default" : null,
            "name" : "testName",
            "type" : ["null","string"]
          }, {
            "name" : "keys",
            "type" : {"type": "array", "items": "string"},
            "java-class" : "java.util.List"
          }]
        },
      "java-class" : "java.util.List"
}
```

The object was written to Kafka successfully using this schema.  But on deserialization I am getting exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()`

Is it possible to use java.util.List class?  I am using confluent 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

A `List` is an interface, it has no constructor or concrete implementation. Your Producer is probably using an ArrayList, and so should the reader schema and  consumer

Make sure the schema is defined with `"java-class" : "java.util.ArrayList"`